# How to convert tensorflow tensor into keras tensor OR resize keras feature map?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to resize the feature map in  `keras` or convert `tensorflow` tensor into `keras` tensor?

I want to resize the out of `keras` layer, and I use  `K.resize_images` , but I failed.

```py
    block1_btchnorm2 = BatchNormalization(name ='b1_bn2')(block1_conv2)
    block1_conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='elu',name='b1_c3')(block1_btchnorm2)
    block1_btchnorm3 = BatchNormalization(name ='b1_bn3')(block1_conv3)
    block1_maxpooling =  MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),name ='b1_mp')(block1_btchnorm3)
    block1_out = K.resize_images(block1_maxpooling, height_factor =64/124 , width_factor = 64/124, data_format='channels_last')
```

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Lambda layer to apply any backend function to a keras tensor:

```
block1_out = Lambda(lambda x: K.resize_images(x, height_factor =64/124 , width_factor = 64/124, data_format='channels_last'))(block1_maxpooling)
```